# DatePickerDialog soft keyboard type has no effect

Tags: android, date

I am implementing a DatePickerDialog in my app and my problem is that when I try to change the "Day" the soft keyboard pops up and shows numbers, while the caret is before the number. When I click numbers it doesn't replace what's already in the "Day" box. Only if I go to the end of the number in the Day box and delete it (backspace in soft keyboard) and then type in the number, it works.

Why is this happening? Why doesn't it override what's already there?

This code displays the dialog:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    Dialog ReturnDialog = null;

    switch (id)
    {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:        
        ReturnDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, Year, Month - 1,  Day );
        break;
    }
    return ReturnDialog;
}
```

Then I call this from an onClickListener()

```
showDialog( DATE_DIALOG_ID );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is(I think) the normal behavior. A `DatePickerDialog` is composed of a single `DatePicker` widget, which is composed from three `NumberPicker` widgets for each date's part(day, month, year). Those `NumberPicker` are composed from `ImageViews` and an `EditText` as the input area. Clicking on an `EditText` to show the keyboard to input data/text *doesn't* erase the old data so the behavior is normal.

You'll have a tough time to override this behavior, especially if you plan to cover older android version because you wouldn't be able to access the input `EditTexts`. For example, you can't access the `DatePicker` widget of the dialog on older android versions, a method to access this widget was added only recently to the `DatePickerDialog`(in `Honeycomb`, API version 11).

Of course you have the option of recreating the `DatePickerDialog` to implement the behavior but I think it doesn't worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am wondering, how did Android avoid this behavior in their own Calendar application? Even in 2.3 this issue was not present in their application, which I assume also uses the DatePickerDialog for new events.

Comment: @EladNava I didn't use/see the default Calendar app, but are you sure that the behavior is present in 2.3? Starting with Honeycomb there is the method `getDatePicker` that could do what you want but below this version I don't see how it could be done.

Comment: Does this mean that 'getDatePicker' would be provided in the Android v4 support library (compatibility package)?

Comment: @EladNava Unfortunately, no. You could look to double check, but the answer is no http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/package-summary.html . If you say that the default Calendar app does what you want maybe looking at the source code might bring a solution https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar

Comment: The problem with using the 4.0.3 Calendar app is that I will need to build my project to the same Android version to have those controls, and I need to be able to support Android 2.2+ :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the "automatically select all text inside when the input box has focus" by adding an [`OnGlobalFocusChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener.html) to your `DatePickerDialog` as follow:

```
private final OnGlobalFocusChangeListener mFocusCheck = new OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus) {
        if (newFocus != null && newFocus instanceof EditText) {
            final EditText editText = (EditText) newFocus;
            editText.selectAll();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;

    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_ID:
            dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, year, month - 1, day) {
                @Override
                public void setView(View view) {
                    super.setView(view);
                    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(mFocusCheck);
                }
            };
            break;
    }

    return dialog;
}
```

However, please note that this might not work for all Android versions since we are relying on some assumptions (mainly the fact that the the `DatePicker` component is implemented internally using a `NumberPicker` which has an embedded `EditText`).

Comparing on the emulator, I noticed that even between Android 4.0 and 4.1, the behavior of the `NumberPicker` is different already (you will need to double tap to get the soft keyboard to show on 4.0, while on 4.1 a single tap is enough).

Comment: Tried the code, unfortunately on 4.0.3 it's already implemented using a NumberPicker, so it had no effect. Is there no way to add support for that as well? I read on NumberPicker and seems like it's private and we can't use it in the SDK without copying the source.